# mongodb master-master replica set

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2, database-replication, amazon-elb

I have the following situation:

2 ec2 instances behind a load balancer, they all have separate dbs(mongodb). What I whant is that these dbs synchronize or replicate with each other.

Mongodb provides 3 solutions, as far as I know:

Slave master replication: This has no use becouse I need both dbs to be master.

Replica Sets: 1 primary db and several secondary, if the primary is taken down the secondary start working. This could work... if the primary is in one server and the secondary in the other. When one server stops responding so would do the db and the other server with the secondary db would become primary.

Sharding: Have the same db splited between both servers. I dont know if is possible to have high redundancy enougth like to have most of the data in both dbs.

What do you think? Is there some other choice?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the use case for master master replication, it sounds like you want automatede failover, replica sets is designed for that

Comment: @leojg, How did u solve this?

Comment: I did not :P 
I used a mongodb replica set and worked like a charm. You can query the secondaries but only save to the primary, thats the most close to a Master Master that mongodb can be.